# Finding the specific frame an animation is on unity 2D

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have a sprite in a 2D project with an animator component in it. I am trying to find a way of getting the current frame that the current animation is on. I have found that if you have specifically added each animation as a component to the sprite you would be able to do something like this:

```
if (animation["attack"].time > 0.333  < animation["attack"].time < 0.5) {
    //do something interesting
}
```

This is assuming that the animation's name is attack, and you are using your games frame rate as a reference. This would be perfect for what I am doing, as I have three different jump animations, each one being used for when the characters walking animation is in a different place in his walk, so it looks more smooth. This however is impossible to do as I'm not using an animation component. I have tried something like this:

```
anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

if (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo().animation.time > 0.333 < anim.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo().animation.time < 0.5) {
    //do something interesting]
}
```

But that doesn't work. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Get the Animators' `AnimatorStateInfo` then its  `AnimatorStateInfo`. Multiply the [`AnimatorClipInfo.clip.length`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip-length.html) with [`AnimatorStateInfo.normalizedTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorStateInfo-normalizedTime.html) to get the current time.

```
 AnimatorStateInfo animationInfo = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
 AnimatorClipInfo[] animationClip = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0);

 float time = animationClip[0].clip.length * animationInfo.normalizedTime;
```

Comment: what are the usual results of `time` you would get from doing this?